# Django deployed app/project can't write to a file

Tags: python, django, apache, apache2.4

I am working on a Django based application whose location on my disk is `home/user/Documents/project/application`. Now this application takes in some values from the user and writes them into a `file` located in a `folder` which is under the `project` directory i.e `home/user/Documents/project/folder/file`. While running the development server using the command `python manage.py runserver` everything worked fine, however after deployment the `application/views.py` which accesses the `file` via `open('folder/path','w')` is not able to access it anymore, because by default it looks in `var/www` folder when deployed via `apache2` server using `mod_wsgi`.

Now, I am not putting the `folder` into `/var/www` because it is not a good practise to put any python code there as it might become readable clients which is a major security threat. Please let me know, how can I point the deployed application to read and write to correct file.

Comment: Do you use absolute paths?

Comment: @ilse2005 I am using relative paths.

Comment: Can't you use absolute path to a location where you have write access?

Comment: @ilse2005 I think you mean where the apache user has write access, right?

Answer (score 0):

The real solution is to install your data files in `/srv/data/myapp` or some such so that you can give the webserver user correct permissions to only those directories. Whether you choose to put your code in `/var/www` or not, is a separate question, but I would suggest putting at least your wsgi file there (and, of course, specifying your `<DocumentRoot..>` correctly.

Comment: As stated on the Django tutorial on the link https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/#creating-a-project I have kept the `wsgi.py` in the location where the `startproject` command created my Django project, nowhere it is mentioned to move it from there.

`DocumentRoot` is currently configured for `/var/www`.

Comment: Production is different from the first chapter of the tutorial... If you want something basic, then you should put your code in standard locations - if that doesn't work for you for some reason you can of course adapt your system as you see fit.  Eg. for my installations, I've got wsgi/settings/root urls in `/srv/www/site1` and `DocumentRoot` for that virtual host is `/srv/www/site1/docroot` (we serve a very few static resources from there like the favicon, the cookie-policy, etc.).  The app code is outside of `/srv/www` and is found by being available in the virtualenv the site is running.